# Multi-level hierarchy powerbi

Tags: powerbi

Today i have this structure in a table :

https://imgur.com/a/ieZnlCT (sorry for the link but there is an error when uploading picture ATM)

When i create a hierarchy based on this structure (the 1st column of my hierarchy is group_id, the 2nd is parent_agency_id and the 3rd is agency_id), the result in my matrix table is not the one i'm expected.

here is the result : https://imgur.com/a/3cPifib

Only 3 levels, but i expect 4 level regarding my data.

For example 1-2 shouldn't appear twice within the matrix but only once (within 1-1). And 1-3 should be within 1-2 (which is the case) but not at this level (i would say, one more level down).

More something like :

```
1
|-- 1-1
     |-- 1-2
          |-- 1-3
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Parent-Child hierarchies, we can leverage the DAX [Parent and Child functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/parent-and-child-functions-dax).

In your table, create the following Calculated Columns (do the first one first).

```
Path = PATH('Your Table'[agency_id], 'Your Table'[parent_agency_id])

Level 1 = PATHITEM([Path], 1)

Level 2 = PATHITEM([Path], 2)

Level 3 = PATHITEM([Path], 3)

Level 4 = PATHITEM([Path], 4)
```

Now you case use Level 1, 2, 3 etc... for your hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what if i have 5 level or 6 or more ? Your solution is not dynamic i guess ?

Comment: This solution isn't dynamic, and with Parent-Child hierarchies it isn't by it's nature. You may find this post a useful read: [Parent-child hierarchies](https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/)

Comment: ok so the best way i guess is to create few more levels column in advance and anticipate. 
For instance if today i have a 4 level hierarchy, i can create 6 or 7 column just in case ?

Comment: Yes, however usually you'll find you won't need to have all the levels. The alternative is to do something similar in Power Query which could be dynamic, however from what I have seen it is fairly complex, where the DAX version is pretty simple.

Comment: the path function is not working in my situation. i got an error message saying that the "" (the empty) value in the parent_id column should also be in the id column. 
When the parent_id column is empty, it means that the id is the first level of the hierarchy. For me it is normal that for some records, the parent_id column is empty.

Comment: It needs to be blank/null and not an empty string. In Powerquery you can replace value to null.